# Knockout.JS loading sequence issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, knockout.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my scripts to load properly for a page that I'm using that has a knockout.js form. As soon as the page loads, my js file containing the viewmodel isn't immediately loaded so there are errors, which causes the page to flash all of my validation messages and displays divs that should be hidden, but then it loads and the form then appears normal.

On main.ctp (cakephp view file) I load a file called loadScripts.JS which contains the following

```
//loadscripts.JS
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
    load_scripts();
});

function load_scripts(){
    $.getScript("localhost/js/knockout-2.3.0.js", function() {
        $.getScript("http://localhost/js/Knockout-Validation/Src/knockout.validation.js", function() {
                retrieve_window();
        });
    });
}
```

So by this point, knockout and knockout-validation are loaded. It then calls a function which is on main.ctp to retrieve the window that contains the knockout form

```
//main.ctp
<script src="/localhost/js/loadscripts.js"></script> <!-- this is the JS file I showed above

function retrieve_window(){
    $.post("/demo/demo_window/1",function(data) {
        $('#window_wrapper').html(data);
    });
}
```

On the demo_window view (cakePHP), the viewmodel is called immediately in the head

```
//demo_window.ctp
<head>
  <script src="localhost/js/demo_form.js"></script>
</head>
```

So the order that the scripts are loaded is (confirmed by network tab in Chrome)

1. Knockout
2. Knockout-Validation
3. demo_form.ctp (knockout powered form)
4. demo_form.js (view-model for form)

I even tried loading demo_form.js in the cluster of $getScripts above but despite loading before demo_form.ctp the form didn't even seem to "see" the js at all. All of the validation errors and hidden divs were displaying. So the load sequence was then (confirmed by network tab in Chrome)

1. Knockout
2. Knockout-Validation
3. demo_form.js (view-model for form)
4. demo_form.ctp (knockout powered form)

The strange thing is this didn't give me any errors. It just displayed as if there were errors (validation messages showing, hidden divs being displayed).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best off using a proper module-loader system (require.js is the one I'm most familiar with and probably the one you'll have the most people able to help you with, but it's not the only one). Such systems, among other things, make sure that no piece of code tries to run until all its dependencies have been loaded and run. They take some up-front learning, but the payoff is large.

A last-resort solution to preventing "Flash of Unstyled/Unbehaviored Content" (FOUC or FUBC) is to set `display: none` on the offending elements via inline `style` attributes and then unhide them in your code. You should not use this, however, to slap a bandage over more fundamental problems.